# An integration problem - series

Tags: real-analysis

> [image]

I think the sum above is uniformly convergent, by $M$ test. So switching the integral and sum is fine.

Evaluating, I got my answer to be

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{\cos( k x) }{k^2}dx &=  \sum_{k \geq 1} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos( k x) }{k^2}dx \\
&=   \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^3} \sin(\pi k / 2) \\
&= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(2n +1)^3} (-1)^{n +1}
\end{align}

Am I completely off? What does it mean to prove my answer here?

**EDIT**: I just checked on Mathematica and the sum is $\frac{i}{2}(Li_4(-i) - Li_4(i))$

which is nothing like my answer, so I am convinced that I am wrong.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{\pi^{3} \over 32}}$

Comment: I just found a mistake in my answer, I forgot the cube. Wolframalpha returns 1 - the answer you gave me

Comment: The last $n$-sum should start at zero. Otherwise you are missing the first term. The correct formula is $\sum_{n \geq 0}{\left(-1\right)^{n} \over \left(2n + 1\right)^{3}}$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn+%3D+0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%28%28-1%29%5En%29%2F%28%282*n+%2B1%29%5E3%29

Comment: My mistake, I wrote $1/k^3$ instead of $1/k^2$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer is correct. So my only mistake is that I typed the incorrect solution and the sum should start at $n = 0$